# Finding out what happened to edit

Tags: support, editing

I asked [Remove elongated, "thin" parts of shapes (preferably R, otherwise python/QGIS)](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/414928) and got a helpful answer that pointed me in the right direction, but was somewhat minimalistic. I edited the [answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/414929/34517), to add **code**, an **example image**, **further description** and optional improvements. The answer showed a banner to me, something like "Edited in a way only I can see until it is approved". This banner now disappeared and the answer is back to it's minimal version.

**Can I find out (or can someone tell me) what happened to an edit *(respectively that specific one)* ?**

I've spent quite some time to significantly improve someone's answer, so that it will help others, after it helped me. It would be heartbreaking and really demotivating, if that work was for nothing. It happened to me once before and I was left wondering, why someone would reject it. Or maybe I just need help to see why someone would reject this particular edit.

If it's gone, I'd rather not go through such a process again or create my own (duplicate and competing, but more elaborate) answer, so that I can be sure it'll be published - cheesy, since I don't want to steal credit for the answer, but in this case I'd argue it'd better.

---

To understand what I'm talking about: Here is left the original answer, on the right with my changes.

[image: Original answer and edited answer.]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To find out about what happend to your edit (or the post in general), you can click on the small "clock" button just below the up/downvote buttons, see encirceled in red:

[image]

This will show you all events, happened to that post:

[image]

If you then click on "suggested edits" you can find your edit suggestion as plain text (so it is not lost and you can copy paste it to a new answer if you wish) as well as whether and the reason why it was rejected.

I am not sure if these actions require special privileges or not.

Answer (score 2):

I was not involved in reviewing your suggested edit but I think it changed that answer too much.  Consequently, I think rejection of your suggested edit was reasonable.  I think you should have written a self-answer instead, and linked to the first answer if that helped you get to yours.

I voted to close your question because it asked for help with code (you said R preferably, or Python as an alternative) without presenting a code attempt.

I have now edited your question to focus it on R, and since you have expressed an intention to provide R code in an answer, I have voted to re-open your question so that you can do that.

Comment: Thank you a lot for clarifying. Making this transparent restored all my faith in this community (that I value a lot) and I do understand the reasoning. I will also use the opportunity to provide the code.

Answer (score 0):

It was rejected, if you feel your answer was worth while then add it as a new answer. But I note the question is now closed anyway.

Comment: Okay, I guess I learned a few things here, even if I don't agree - neither with the approach to **duplicate answers in order to improve an already existing one**, nor with the "off-topic" flag on my question. I wasn't looking to "improve code", I was looking for a tool/approach, shared my research and thoughts so far - after I had an answer to this approach, I knew what code to produce - and thought it'd be best to share. I stand corrected.

Comment: Question has been re-opened and self-answered.